# How to map() a Stream until it is cancelled in Dart?

Tags: asynchronous, dart

I have a `Stream` I get from a database query. I believe the query will run for some time, producing values as it runs, so i wanted to be able to show the user the items as soon as they become available.

But once the user picks an item, I want the Stream to be cancelled.

I am having trouble writing this because I don't see how I can both get a subscription to the stream that can be cancelled later AND at the same time map over its elements, so that the consumer of my mapped stream can process items as they are produced by the original Stream.

Basically, I think I need something like a `CancellableStream`, but I don't see anything like that in the Dart SDK.

I've tried something like this so far:

```
final subscription = cursor.listen((entry) => process(entry));
// now I can cancel the subscription when needed, but how to
// return the processed items to the caller?

final processed = cursor.map((entry) => process(entry));
// now I have the processed Stream I wanted, but how can I cancel it?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `where(...)` using the state of `hasPicked` should do what you want

```
bool hasPicked = false;
...
final processed = cursor.where((entry) => !hasPicked).map((entry) => process(entry));
```

When the user has picked one, set `hasPicked` to `true`.

Comment: This is brilliant. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Based on https://www.dartlang.org/articles/libraries/creating-streams...

Here's a simple implementation of a cancellable Stream:

```
class CancellableStream<T> {
  final Stream<T> _originalStream;
  bool _isCancelled = false;

  CancellableStream(this._originalStream);

  Stream<T> get stream async* {
    await for (final item in _originalStream) {
      if (_isCancelled) break;
      yield item;
    }
  }

  void cancel() => _isCancelled = true;
}
```